# use packages installed with opam inside utop

Tags: ocaml, opam, utop

I installed yojson with opam:

```
opam install yojson
```

and I want to use it inside utop, but I haven't been able to make it work. I've tried these commands inside utop and none of them worked (it complains that it can't find the file / package):

```
#use "Yojson";;
#use "yojson";;
#require "Yojson";;
#require "yojson";;
```

Is there any additional configuration I should be aware of to use opam packages in utop?

Comment: `#require "yojson";;`  is the correct version (in fact `utop` should suggest you a list of possible completion as you are typing the name). `#use` directive is for loading a `.ml` source script, not a compiled package (hence the message complaining about a file and not package as with `#requires`). What you describe suggests an issue with your installation. Did you install `utop` with `opam` as well?

Comment: I installed utop and yojson with opam, but it still doesn't work. It's probably some strange error with my installation. It worked on my other computer.

Answer (score 4):

The correct invocation is (include the `#` character):

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "yojson";;
```

The first command enables the `#require` directive (it is not the standard one, but comes from the `ocamlfind` tool), it is a good idea to add it to your `~/.ocamlinit` file, if it is not there already. The second directive, actually loads the `yojson` library. You can also use the `#list` directive to list all available packages, as well as the `ocamlfind list` shell command for the same puprose.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I was under the impression that `utop` was automatically doing the first step for you.

Comment: any idea on how to do this from a dune project that has a dune file that depends on yojson? I was trying `dune utop .` or `dune utop lib` but `open Yojson` never works from there

Comment: @David天宇Wong, you can use the same directives, e.g., `#require "yojson"`

Comment: it doesn't matter if I'm starting this from dune utop right? The only thing that matters when using require is the switch I'm using and the installed world?

Comment: It matters as dune will automatically load the project dependencies, but yes,  the switch has to be activated and the package shall be installed.